# How file join for component creation (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, components, workflow

I'm developing a workflow based on atomic design. It's still static.
I created the folder with the components, with the following structure:

```
/components
 /atoms
   - button.css
   - button.hmtl
   - button.js
 /molecules
   - header.css
   - header.hmtl
   - header.js
 /organisms
 /templates
```

I want to build components.
So I want to create the templates and use the html / css / js only of the elements that put in each page.
No need to use the whole application code.

How do I join the css/html/js of each element in one files in a single file?
One file for each, html, css, js
Can I do it with the gulp?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the CSS you want in a single file, then your intuition is right about Gulp, it would probably be the easiest solution. I would recommend using [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) which is designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Actually I want to build components.
So I want to create the templates and use the html / css / js only of the elements that put in each page.
No need to use the whole application code.